# mat-table lock or pin to start column Material 2 Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm using mat-table in my angular 5 project.

the current result is as follows :

[image]

I'd like to be able to "pin" a column.
you'd click on these pins and "pinned" columns would come to the leftmost and stay above others when you **scroll-x** (as you can see me do in the gif above).

the css allowing scroll-x is (for example, mine is much bigger and dynamic) :

```
.mat-header-row, .mat-row {
    width: 1500px;
}
```

Much the way excel locked columns/rows do.

(I scroll X ALOT since my column numbers are in the high 80's to hundreds and some of them need to be quite wide.)

I've made a photoshop mockup to give you an idea what I'm talking about :

[image]

For example the select checkboxes should always be "pinned". That is, they remain visible when you horizontally scroll.

here's my code :

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

<ng-container matColumnDef="select">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
    <mat-checkbox
      (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
      [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
      [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
    </mat-checkbox>
  </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
    <mat-checkbox
      (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
      (change)="$event ? addToSelection(row, $event, true) : null"
      [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
    </mat-checkbox>
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngFor="let col of displayedColumns" matColumnDef={{col}}>
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
       {{ startCase(col) }} </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row[col]}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumnsWSelect"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumnsWSelect;"
         class="noselect"
         [ngClass]="{ 'selected': selection.isSelected(row)}"
         (click)="addToSelection(row, $event, false)"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

And I'm persuaded, but I may be wrong, that there's a hurdle thrown at me by me iterating over the array elements and their objects (like I do), rather than declaring each column in the DOM.

However, this is a functionality I cannot forgo.

I'd love to just say : "ok your `pinned` var is set to true so you get the `[ngClass]` 'pinned' which in css translate to you being `position: absolute` and `left: 0`"

ok but that's no help if I want to pin several. they'll just end up one on top of one another.

The other issue I see is once I've done that haven't I lost the "pin header" functionality I added for those pinned columns?

Comment: I found this https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/left_right_columns.html but I don't really like the prospect of switching to data tables.

Comment: I'm gonna try to solve this by making two distinct tables and updating their respective displayedColumns array making them trade columns when they get pined and unpinned and finally syncing both of their scroll-y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've since implemented my own idea for a solution : simply having two mat tables.

that process was easy enough and uninteresting but I though you might be interested by the code I wrote to sync both tables :

ts :

```
  leftS;
  rightS;
  leftTimeout;
  rightTimeout;
  syncScrollRightBeingCalled = false;
  syncScrollLeftBeingCalled = false;

  constructor(
    private element: ElementRef) {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.leftS = this.element.nativeElement.querySelector('.catching-scrolling-left');
    this.rightS = this.element.nativeElement.querySelector('.catching-scrolling-right');
  }

  syncScrollLeft(div){
    clearTimeout(this.leftTimeout);
    if(!this.syncScrollRightBeingCalled){
      this.syncScrollLeftBeingCalled = true;
      this.leftS.scrollTop = div.scrollTop;
    }
    this.leftTimeout = setTimeout(() => this.syncScrollLeftBeingCalled = false, 25);
  }
  syncScrollRight(div){
    clearTimeout(this.rightTimeout);
    if(!this.syncScrollLeftBeingCalled) {
      this.syncScrollRightBeingCalled = true;
      this.rightS.scrollTop = div.scrollTop;
    }
    this.rightTimeout = setTimeout(() => this.syncScrollRightBeingCalled = false, 25);
  }
```

html :

```
<mat-table #table1 [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="pinned catching-scrolling-right" (scroll)="syncScrollLeft($event.srcElement)">
<mat-table #table2 [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="unpinned catching-scrolling-left" (scroll)="syncScrollRight($event.srcElement)">
```

css :

```
.unpinned{
  height: calc(100vh - 430px);
}
.pinned{
  height: calc(100vh - 447px);
}
.pinned{
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 560px;
}
.unpinned{
  overflow: scroll;
  flex: 1;
}
/deep/ .pinned::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
}
```

this has relatively satisfactory results. I'll have to figure out one day why it doesn't work under firefox, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your columns order if defined by your displayedColumnsWSelect variable. Change the values order in that array and your columns order will change.

Here is a stackblitz demonstrating that:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q7nibn

Click on the top button "Put last column first" and the last column becomes the first.

That's for moving the columns. Now if you want to keep track of what columns have been pinned so you can set the order right, your just need another object/array containing that information.

Comment: I'm not sure you quite understood exactly what I'm going after. thanks for going and making a stackblitz but look at the added Gif in my question which makes my question more clear.

Comment: Yep I get it now. Then i think your idea of two tables, although hacky, could do the trick...